# Retrieving a few fields from large response object

Tags: java, spring, google-directory-api

I am making a call to Google Directory API  and only need a few fields it is returning. I am fairly new to Java/Spring so I am trying to figure out what is the best way to go about this. I am making my request like this:

`restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, req, Object, userKey);`

I currently have it as an Object, but not sure if this is correct. I do not want to map out the very large object it returns when I only need a few fields. Is there a way to access the fields, `phone, organizations, locations` ?

`res.getClass().getField("phones")` did not work for me.

For purposes we can consider the shape of the object:

```
{ 
    phones: [type: String, number: String], 
    organizations: [title: String], 
    locations: [buildingId: String]  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your response JSON as JsonNode.

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree("[your JSON here]");
After that get only fields, which you need. For example:

jsonNode.get("request").get("phones").get("type").asText()

or just a phones object

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do something like below. Here "User" is **com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User**

```
    List<User> users = result.getUsers();
    if (users == null || users.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No users found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Users:");
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.getName().getFullName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to find this package. What do I add to build.gradle?